# In Nodejs, how to blpop from redis on multiple queues

Tags: node.js, redis

I am using Redis npm library for Redis connection.

I am able to blpop from single queue like below

```
redis.blpop('firstQueue', timeOut, (err, reply) => {
        console.log(reply);
});
```

But I want to pop from multiple queues like below

```
redis.blpop(['firstQueue', 'secondQueue', 'thrirdQueue'], timeOut, (err, reply) => {
            console.log(reply);
 });
```

But pop from multiple queue are not working.

I am using npm library Redis [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works but beware I am not sure if this is efficient and if it's good practice

```
client.batch().blpop('firstQueue', timeOut)
.blpop('secondQueue', timeOut)
.blpop('thrirdQueue', timeOut).exec(function(err, reply) {
  if (err) console.log(err)

  console.log(reply)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

*(This question is old but just in case...)*

If the package does not provide the function to `blpop` on several list at the same time (whereas redis allows this), you can directly try the sendCommand function:

`redis.sendCommand(command: string, cb?: Callback<any>): boolean;`

with command string being something like `BLPOP firstQueue secondQueue thrirdQueue ${timeOut}`

(see redis doc: https://redis.io/commands/blpop )